# Mounting network share with CIFS stopped working on 17.10

Tags: networking, permissions, mount, fstab, cifs

With Ubuntu 17.04, I had created the following line in /etc/fstab to permanently mount a network drive. It worked perfectly.

```
//nas/shared/ /media/nas cifs username=(username),password=(pass),uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm  0  0
```

However, the same code isn't working in Ubuntu 17.10 (clean installation, not an update). It shows the shared folder, but clicking on it throws an "operation permitted for root only" message.

[Error Message 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmohY.png)

You should note that I have done the necessary chown -R on the /media/nas folder.

I even tried to access the share with a sudo nautilus, and I am getting this error.

[Error Message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSbzf.png)

I have extensively read the MountWindowsSharesPermanently page on the Ubuntu wiki, but to no avail.

Any idea what I am doing wrong? Or could it be just a 17.10 bug?

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same symptoms and solved it by specifying using SMB1, for you that would be modifying it to be:

```
//nas/shared/ /media/nas cifs username=(username),password=(pass),uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,vers=1.0  0  0
```

If you want to be sure check your logs for cifs related messages.

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked, in conjunction with replacing //nas/shared with //nas.local/shared

Comment: Be aware that Samba 1 has major security issues. http://www.zdnet.com/article/windows-10-tip-stop-using-the-horribly-insecure-smbv1-protocol/ Windows article, but you get the idea.

Comment: While this does get rid of the error message, it's not a great solution. Does anyone know how we should be connecting to an SMB v2 (or v3) share without getting error messages?

Answer (score 0):

I removed `sec=ntlm` from my fstab-mounted shares and that got rid of the errors.

This worked

```
//[server]/[share] /media/[mountpoint] cifs credentials=[credentialfile],iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=[me],gid=[me] 0 0
```

This didn't

```
 //[server]/[share] /media/[mountpoint] cifs credentials=[credentialfile],iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,uid=[me],gid=[me] 0 0
```

It threw `mount error(22): Invalid argument`

It appears `sec=ntlm` has been invalidated.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't work for me. Elgorath's solution worked, but it still needs the sec=ntlm, won't function without it. In any case, thank you for your input.

Comment: I have a feeling the answer to this may depend on one's samba settings for the share.